# PHPSecLib split commands

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib, libssh2

I am using PHPSecLib to send commands via SSH to network switches, which works fine in most cases. I have had to make a few modifications to support a different brand, however it appears that sending the commands via write() is resulting in these being split.

I have never seen anything like this and I am beyond stumped as to what is causing it. Is there anything in PHPSecLib/SSH that would force command line strings to a certain length?

Command Line Output:

```
configure Entering configuration mode
{master:0}[edit]
LHBR@EVO-HN11-1# set policy-options prefix-list ddosHost 183.24.48.7 255. 
LHBR@EVO-HN11-1# ...ix-list ddosHost 183.24.48.7 255.2 55.255.255 ^ syntax error. 
{master:0}[edit]
LHBR@EVO-HN11-1# commit configuration check succeeds commit complete 
{master:0}[edit] 
LHBR@EVO-HN11-1# exit Exiting configuration mode 
{master:0} 
LHBR@EVO-HN11-1>
```

Function:

```
public function write_msg($msg)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($msg); $i++)
    {
        $this->conn->write($msg[$i]);
    }
}

public function create_nullroute($ip, $netmask = "255.255.255.255")
{

    $this->write_msg("configure\n");
    $this->write_msg("set policy-options prefix-list ddosHost " . $ip . " " . $netmask . "\n");
    $this->write_msg("commit\n");

    // Escape the config mode
    $this->conn->write("exit\n");

    echo "</br><pre>" . $this->conn->getLog() . "</pre>";

    echo $this->conn->read($this->_bashshell);
}
```

PHPSecLib Log:

```
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 0.005, network: 0s)


<- NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 0, network: 0s)


-> NET_SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST (since last: 0.0028, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:0c:73:73:68:2d:75:73:65:72:61:75:74:68  ....ssh-userauth

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT (since last: 0.5057, network: 0.5056s)
00000000  00:00:00:0c:73:73:68:2d:75:73:65:72:61:75:74:68  ....ssh-userauth

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:08:75:73:65:72:6e:61:6d:65:00:00:00:0e  ....username....
00000010  73:73:68:2d:63:6f:6e:6e:65:63:74:69:6f:6e:00:00  ssh-connection..
00000020  00:08:70:61:73:73:77:6f:72:64:00:00:00:00:08:70  ..password.....p
00000030  61:73:73:77:6f:72:64                             assword

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS (since last: 0.2388, network: 0.2387s)


-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:07:73:65:73:73:69:6f:6e:00:00:00:01:7f  ....session.....
00000010  ff:ff:ff:00:00:40:00                             .....@.

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION (since last: 0.2093, network: 0.2092s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:80:00  ................

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:07:70:74:79:2d:72:65:71:01  ........pty-req.
00000010  00:00:00:05:76:74:31:30:30:00:00:00:50:00:00:00  ....vt100...P...
00000020  18:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:00        ..............

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS (since last: 0.2233, network: 0.2232s)
00000000  00:00:00:01                                      ....

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:05:73:68:65:6c:6c:01        ........shell.

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_WINDOW_ADJUST (since last: 0.2153, network: 0.2153s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:20:00:00                          ..... ..

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:01                                      ....

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0158, network: 0.0157s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:32:2d:2d:2d:20:4a:55:4e:4f  .......2--- JUNO
00000010  53:20:31:32:2e:33:52:33:2e:34:20:62:75:69:6c:74  S 12.3R3.4 built
00000020  20:32:30:31:33:2d:30:36:2d:31:34:20:30:30:3a:30   2013-06-14 00:0
00000030  36:3a:33:34:20:55:54:43:0d:0a                    6:34 UTC..

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.6052, network: 0.6051s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:0c:7b:6d:61:73:74:65:72:3a  ........{master:
00000010  30:7d:0d:0a                                      0}..

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0016, network: 0.0015s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:11:4c:48:42:52:40:45:56:4f  ........LHBR@EVO
00000010  2d:48:4e:31:31:2d:31:3e:20                       -HN11-1> 

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:18:73:65:74:20:63:6c:69:20  ........set cli 
00000010  73:63:72:65:65:6e:2d:6c:65:6e:67:74:68:20:30:0a  screen-length 0.

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.207, network: 0.207s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:73                       ........s

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0015, network: 0.0014s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0015, network: 0.0015s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:74                       ........t

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0047, network: 0.0046s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0014, network: 0.0014s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:63                       ........c

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0025, network: 0.0024s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:6c                       ........l

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0015, network: 0.0015s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:69                       ........i

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0039, network: 0.0039s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0016, network: 0.0015s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:73                       ........s

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0021, network: 0.002s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:63                       ........c

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0016, network: 0.0015s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:72                       ........r

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0014, network: 0.0014s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0017, network: 0.0017s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0047, network: 0.0046s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:6e                       ........n

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0002, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:2d                       ........-

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:6c                       ........l

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0009, network: 0.0009s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:6e                       ........n

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0016, network: 0.0016s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:67                       ........g

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0022, network: 0.0021s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:74                       ........t

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0016, network: 0.0015s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:68                       ........h

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0041, network: 0.004s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0016, network: 0.0015s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:30                       ........0

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0048, network: 0.0047s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0023, network: 0.0022s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:02:0d:0a                    ..........

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0048, network: 0.0048s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:18:53:63:72:65:65:6e:20:6c  ........Screen l
00000010  65:6e:67:74:68:20:73:65:74:20:74:6f:20:30:0d:0a  ength set to 0..

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0021, network: 0.002s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:02:0d:0a                    ..........

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0043, network: 0.0043s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:0c:7b:6d:61:73:74:65:72:3a  ........{master:
00000010  30:7d:0d:0a                                      0}..

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:11:4c:48:42:52:40:45:56:4f  ........LHBR@EVO
00000010  2d:48:4e:31:31:2d:31:3e:20                       -HN11-1> 

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:63                       ........c

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6f                       ........o

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6e                       ........n

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:66                       ........f

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:69                       ........i

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:67                       ........g

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:75                       ........u

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:72                       ........r

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:0a                       .........

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:73                       ........s

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:74                       ........t

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:70                       ........p

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6f                       ........o

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6c                       ........l

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:69                       ........i

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:63                       ........c

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:79                       ........y

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:2d                       ........-

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6f                       ........o

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:70                       ........p

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:74                       ........t

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:69                       ........i

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6f                       ........o

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6e                       ........n

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:73                       ........s

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:70                       ........p

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:72                       ........r

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:66                       ........f

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:69                       ........i

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:78                       ........x

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:2d                       ........-

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6c                       ........l

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:69                       ........i

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:73                       ........s

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:74                       ........t

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:64                       ........d

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:64                       ........d

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6f                       ........o

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:73                       ........s

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:48                       ........H

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6f                       ........o

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:73                       ........s

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:74                       ........t

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:31                       ........1

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:38                       ........8

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:35                       ........5

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:2e                       .........

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:31                       ........1

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:36                       ........6

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:2e                       .........

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:38                       ........8

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:34                       ........4

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:2e                       .........

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:37                       ........7

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:30                       ........0

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:32                       ........2

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:35                       ........5

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:35                       ........5

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:2e                       .........

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:32                       ........2

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:35                       ........5

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:35                       ........5

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:2e                       .........

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:32                       ........2

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:35                       ........5

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:35                       ........5

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:2e                       .........

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:32                       ........2

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:35                       ........5

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:35                       ........5

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:0a                       .........

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:63                       ........c

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6f                       ........o

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6d                       ........m

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:6d                       ........m

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:69                       ........i

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:74                       ........t

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:0a                       .........

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:05:65:78:69:74:0a           ........exit.
```

Comment: Logs would help. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and then `$ssh->getLog()` after `create_nullroute` has run.

Comment: I forgot about those but have added them now.

Comment: @BrettPowell I know it has been almost 3 years but did you find a solution for this issue? I'm facing the same problem now.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try throwing some `$ssh->read()`'s in there. In my experience if you just send command after command without doing any read()'s in between then you may be sending them too fast, before the previous command has had a chance to run.

Comment: Thanks, although I already tried that with no luck. I figured that may be the case and did try throwing some read() in after each line  but it seems to actually be a cap somewhere on the length of the string being sent in write().

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

This is just a guess but instead of doing `$this->conn->write("configure\n");` try writing one character at a time. eg.

```
$cmd = "configure\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($cmd); $i++) {
    $this->conn->write($cmd[$i]);
}
```

**Long Answer:**

```
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0a:63:6f:6e:66:69:67:75:72  ........configur
00000010  65:0a                                            e.

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.1027, network: 0.1026s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:63                       ........c

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0012, network: 0.0011s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:08:6f:6e:66:69:67:75:72:65  ........onfigure

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0047, network: 0.0046s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0118, network: 0.0118s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:02:0d:0a                    ..........

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0015, network: 0.0015s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:1d:45:6e:74:65:72:69:6e:67  ........Entering
00000010  20:63:6f:6e:66:69:67:75:72:61:74:69:6f:6e:20:6d   configuration m
00000020  6f:64:65:0d:0a                                   ode..

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0019, network: 0.0018s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:02:0d:0a                    ..........

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0013, network: 0.0013s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:23:7b:6d:61:73:74:65:72:3a  .......#{master:
00000010  30:7d:5b:65:64:69:74:5d:0d:0a:4c:48:42:52:40:45  0}[edit]..LHBR@E
00000020  56:4f:2d:48:4e:31:31:2d:31:23:20                 VO-HN11-1# 

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:45:73:65:74:20:70:6f:6c:69  .......Eset poli
00000010  63:79:2d:6f:70:74:69:6f:6e:73:20:70:72:65:66:69  cy-options prefi
00000020  78:2d:6c:69:73:74:20:64:64:6f:73:48:6f:73:74:20  x-list ddosHost 
00000030  31:38:35:2e:31:36:2e:38:34:2e:37:30:20:32:35:35  186.26.81.23 255
00000040  2e:32:35:35:2e:32:35:35:2e:32:35:35:0a           .255.255.255.

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:07:63:6f:6d:6d:69:74:0a     ........commit.
```

So the server is echo'ing back each command after you send it. What's interesting is that it's kinda doing it haphazardly. Like in the case of configure, which is being sent over as one packet, the response you're getting back is having it split up into two packets.

After that you're sending over the next two commands the server isn't doing anything with them. It's not echo'ing them or anything. And then the connection is just being closed.

This raises a couple of questions.

1. You shouldn't be getting responses back unless you're calling `$this->conn->read()` after those commands. Are you? If so then the code in your original post isn't up-to-date.
2. The CLI output you've posted doesn't match what you're getting in the phpseclib logs. The output that the phpseclibs would have produced is as follows:

   ```
   2--- JUNOS 12.3R3.4 built 2013-06-14 00:06:34 UTC
   {master:0}
   biss@EVO-HN11-1> set cli screen-length 0
   Screen length set to 0
   {master:0}
   LHBR@EVO-HN1-1> configure
   Entering configuration mode
   #{master:0}[edit]
   LHBR@EVO-HN11-1#
   ```

So there are certain discrepancies that are present in your post, however, none-the-less, I do have one idea based on what you've posted thus far.

Instead of doing `$this->conn->write("configure\n");` try writing one character at a time. eg.

```
$cmd = "configure\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($cmd); $i++) {
    $this->conn->write($cmd[$i]);
}
```

Comment: I apologize, I was testing various changes and may have made some small edits before I reran it to generate the logs. I tried the changes you suggested which made sense but unfortunately did not work as hoped. I have updated the output/code/logs in my original post though if you happen to spot anything. Thank you!

Comment: Also to answer your questions, I do not read() in between any of the calls, only at the end once everything has been sent. The CLI output I pasted should be 100% accurate now.

Comment: You must be doing `read()`'s before you're calling the `create_nullroute` method because yo're getting the initial prompt and there's a "set cli screen-length 0" command that's being sent that isn't in your `create_nullroute` method.

Comment: In light of that try undoing the change I had you make where it sends one character at a time and try doing some `$ssh->read()` calls between each of the `$ssh->write()`s. And if that doesn't work *then* post the logs. As is it's possible one of the commands is error'ing out and causing the server to kill te connection but there's no way to know which one unless you actually do the `$ssh->read()` calls.